# Why I don't see the GUI box in the center of the screen ? Not see it at all

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DetectInteractable : UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera cam;
    public float distanceToSee;
    public string objectHit;
    public bool interactableObject = false;
    public Transform parentToSearch;
    public Scaling scaling;
    public LayerMask layermask;
    public int spinX = 0;
    public int spinY = 0;
    public int spinZ = 0;
    public GameObject navi;

    private RaycastHit whatObjectHit;
    private bool clickForDescription = false;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !scaling.scaleUp)
        {
            clickForDescription = true;

            if (whatObjectHit.collider != null)
                ExecuteActions(whatObjectHit.collider.gameObject);
        }

        Debug.DrawRay(cam.transform.position, cam.transform.forward * distanceToSee, Color.magenta);
        if (Physics.Raycast(cam.transform.position, cam.transform.forward, out whatObjectHit, distanceToSee, layermask.value)) //layerMask))
        {
            objectHit = whatObjectHit.collider.gameObject.name;
            interactableObject = true;
            print("Hit ! " + whatObjectHit.collider.gameObject.name);

            if (scaling.objectToScale.transform.localScale == scaling.minSize)
            {
                scaling.objectToScale.transform.Rotate(spinX, spinY, spinZ);
            }
            clickForDescription = true;
        }
        else
        {

            if (scaling.objectToScale.transform.localScale == scaling.minSize)
            {
                navi.transform.rotation = new Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 0);
            }
            clickForDescription = false;
            print("Not Hit !");
        }
    }

    private void ExecuteActions(GameObject go)
    {
        var ia = go.GetComponent<ItemAction>();
        if (ia != null)
        {
            ia.ItemMove();
        }
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        if (clickForDescription == true)
        {
            ProcessOnGUI(parentToSearch);
            clickForDescription = false;
        }
    }

    void ProcessOnGUI(Transform parent, int level = 0)
    {
        foreach (Transform child in parent)
        {
            if (child.GetComponent<ItemInformation>() != null)
            {
                ItemInformation iteminformation = child.GetComponent<ItemInformation>();
                if (child.name == objectHit)
                {
                    var centeredStyle = GUI.skin.GetStyle("Label");
                    centeredStyle.alignment = TextAnchor.UpperCenter;
                    GUI.Box(new Rect(
                          Screen.width / 2 /*- 50 + 20 * level*/, // <== INDENTATION
                          Screen.height / 2 ,100,50),/*- 25, 100, 50),*/
                        iteminformation.description, centeredStyle);
                }
            }
            // Process next deeper level
            ProcessOnGUI(child, level + 1);
        }
    }

    public class ViewableObject : UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour
    {
        public string displayText;
        public bool isInteractable;
    }
}
```

It's getting to this line using a break point :

```
GUI.Box(new Rect(
```

And there is a description for the object that was hit.

But when running the game and it's getting to the box part it's not showing anything. There is no any exception/s it's just not showing the box.

The part with the GUI.Box original was like that but it didn't show anything either :

```
GUI.Box(new Rect(
                          Screen.width / 2 - 50 + 20 * level, // <== INDENTATION
                          Screen.height / 2 - 25, 100, 50),
                        iteminformation.description, centeredStyle);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say because you set

```
clickForDescription = false;
```

right after it so the next time it is not displayed anymore.

Note that in contrary to `Update` the

> [`OnGUI`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnGUI.html) is called for rendering and handling GUI events.
>
> This means that your OnGUI implementation might be called **several times per frame** (one call per event).

so maybe it is called the first time but since you set the flag to false in the next call the box is not drawn anymore. What you will finally see as rendered frame is the very last call of `OnGUI` so probably always a one where `clickForDescription` is already `false`.

---

In general you should not use `OnGUI` anymore except for editor scripting.

Rather use the ["new" UI System](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/the-new-ui) instead that was introduced in Unity 4.6 (2015).

So instead of using `clickForDescription` and `OnGUI` I would rather create the UI using `Canvas`, `Image` and `Text` components and then instead enable and disable that parent canvas GameObject in the according spots.